# Maximum OR values in all subsets of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, subset, bitwise-operators

Given an array of n integers. Find the minimum length of the subset with the maximum OR value among all subsets of the given array.

How to go about solving this??

Answer (score 2):

The maximum OR is just the OR of all items, the only real problem is finding the smallest subset that ORs to that value.

This is the search version of the Set Cover problem, both in the sense that it obviously can be solved by treating it as an instance of the search version of Set Cover and in the sense that you could write a Set Cover instance in terms of this problem, so it's NP-hard (not NP-complete because it's not a decision problem).

You could solve that with Integer Linear Programming, SAT solving (costs several queries since SAT does not optimize), Dynamic Programming, and no doubt other techniques.

---

For example, to use DP we could do something such as the following, assuming WLOG<sup>*</sup> that the OR of the input array (`A`) is `m` which is a power of two minus 1. (* because any bit positions that are always 0 can be disregarded and removed from the problem without changing the resulting subset)

Build up a table of sizes `S` such that `S[i][x]` is the size of the smallest subset of `A[0..i]` that covers the mask `x`.

```
S[0][0] = 0
for x in 1..m+1:
    S[0][x] = n+1
for i in 0..n:
    for x in 0..m+1:
        S[i+1][x] = min(S[i][x & ~A[i]] + 1, S[i][x])
```

The size of the minimum cover is found in `S[n][m]` and the cover itself can be reconstructed in the usual "backwards path following" method. If the `min` resulted in its left operand that corresponds to including item `i`, if the `min` resulted in its right operand that corresponds to *not* including item `i`, if it's ambiguous then either path will lead to an equally good solution.

This algorithm cannot take advantage of any useful structure a problem instance might have, unlike a SAT or ILP based algorithm.

Comment: Could this be solved using **Dynamic Programming**?If yes, need a code in the above mentioned.Or just a self explanatory algorithm would be enough.